# Cumulative sum of array items

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, algorithm, logic

I have an sorted array having values like below: I need to calculate total as below:

**Scenario 1 - Array values 12,15,17**

```
12+15 = 27 
27+17 = 44 
44+27 = 71
Total = 71
```

**Scenario 2 Array values 12,15,17,19**

```
12+15 = 27
27+17 = 44
44+19 = 63
27+44+63 = 134
```

Total = 134

**Scenario 3 Array values 12,15,17,19,23**

```
12+15 = 27
27+17 = 44
44+19 = 63
63+23 = 86
27+44+63+86 = 220
```

Total = 220

**Scenario 4 till N Array values 12,15,17,19,23.....N**

I have to bring the above logic to C# code

I have written as below :

```
  int[] myNumbers = new int[] { 100,250,1000};

            Array.Sort(myNumbers);
            int sum = 0;
            int temp = 0;

            foreach (int y in myNumbers)
            {
                sum = sum + y;              
            }

            for(int i=0;i<myNumbers.Length-1;i++)
            {
               temp = temp + myNumbers[i];      
            }

           sum = sum + temp;

           Console.Write(sum);
```

The above code works fine for array values 100,250,1000

But it fails for any other array values

Need help!

Comment: What does "it fails" mean? Any exceptions? Unexpected results?

Comment: no exceptions , the give input works fine...but if we change the array value more numbers it will fail

Comment: @SmartestVEGA he asked what failes and you just answer that it `fails`... what kind of answer is that?

Comment: 100,250,1000,2000

Comment: It does not fail. It just have wrong implementation.

Comment: What exactly happens if you provide "more numbers". Please don´t say "it fails", but what results you get in this case and what you expected instead.

Comment: Sum is taken twice deliberately as we are calculating the time of merging up the time in secs of three arrays, lets say P ,Q,R   . So P & Q takes 12+15 = 27 then 27 + R = 27+17 =44, both merges together it take 27+44 secs =71 secs

Comment: 100,250,1000,1350 , gives 4050, but expected is 350+1350+1350 =2700

Comment: First of all a `Cumulative Sum` returns a list partial sums with count equal to number of elements in the array. Second of all, your sum calculation examples are completely incorrect. And third, you calculate only single value that is the complete sum of all numbers. So what is the exact result that you want to achieve? Is it still a `Cumulative Sum` ?

Comment: sorry my mistake , i corrected the question scenarios .. please have a look at question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

So if you want to get exact results as in your examples, you can use this method.
It will return you an array of partial sums, that you can later sum up to get the result:

```
private static long[] CumulativeSums(long[] values)
{
    if (values == null || values.Length <= 1) return new long[0];

    var results = new long[values.Length];
    results[0] = values[0] + values[1];

    for (var i = 1; i < values.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        results[i] = results[i - 1] + values[i + 1];
    }

    return results;
}
```

And the use it as this:

```
var numbers = new long[] { 12, 15, 17, 19 };
var sumOfCumulativeSums = CumulativeSums(numbers).Sum();
```

And `sumOfCumulativeSums` will be 134.

**Option 2**

But the actual correct representation of cumulative sum is: `a, a+b, a+b+c, ...`. So if you want the correct representation of method that returns you proper cumulative sums, you can use this method instead:

```
public static long[] CumulativeSums(long[] values)
{
    if (values == null || values.Length == 0) return new long[0];

    var results = new long[values.Length];
    results[0] = values[0];

    for (var i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        results[i] = results[i - 1] + values[i];
    }

    return results;
}
```

**Edit**

Hope this helps you to solve your problem in either of ways, and if you have any questions or edits about the code, please ask.

Comment: i tried 100,250,1000, i am getting 1050 for first function and 300 for second function ...i am expecting 1700 ...

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0mCPuz  have a look the code i changed from your logic what went wrong sum function is not available

Comment: @SmartestVEGA did you see the important part `CumulativeSums(numbers).Sum()` not just `CumulativeSums(numbers)`, so please try that function with a `.Sum()`, because that method returns you an array of Cumulative sums

Comment: got it markiian... i added linq and it worked like charm

Answer (score 1):

You can also obtain the sum without any intermediary array allocation:

```
static int Cumulate( int[] numbers )
{
    if ( numbers == null || numbers.Length < 2 )
        return 0;

    Array.Sort( numbers );

    var prevsum = numbers[0] + numbers[1];
    var sum = prevsum;

    for ( int i = 2 ; i < numbers.Length ; i++ )
    {
        prevsum += numbers[i];
        sum += prevsum;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: this case sum is not same as .Sum()

Comment: sub total 350
 sub total 1350
 Sum 2250