# Sum all numbers before specific number (including the number)

Tags: c#

I want to write a program which takes an array of size `N`, loop over it and sum all the numbers before `i` (including `i` itself). I haven't done a lot so far because I don't know how to access the indexs before `i`. When I try for example `arr[i - 1]`, it throws me an error that the index was outside the array bounds.

```cs
int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int[] arr = new int[N];

// Input
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    arr[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

// Here we need to sum
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
//
```

**Example (N = 4)**

```cs
Before = [1, 2, 3, 4]
After = [1, 3, 6, 10]
```

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823467/using-linq-to-find-the-cumulative-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers-in-c-sharp , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53759443/cumulative-sum-of-array-items , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184812/how-to-compute-a-running-sum-of-a-series-of-ints-in-a-linq-query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cumulative sum of an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335660/cumulative-sum-of-an-array)

Comment: @DragandDrop It's weird that I haven't found that stuff, I already Googled.

Comment: And yes `arr[i - 1]` when `i=0` is `arr[-1]` and -1 is out of bound perhaps start at i=1. Try to sum the first element with the previous non existing one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cumulative sum of array items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53759443/cumulative-sum-of-array-items)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compute a running sum of a series of ints in a Linq query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184812/how-to-compute-a-running-sum-of-a-series-of-ints-in-a-linq-query)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can initialize the result array with the correct size beforehand and then use a plain loop to calculate the "running sum". You need a variable to track the current value:

```
int[] result = new int[arr.Length];
int currentSum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    currentSum += arr[i];
    result[i] = currentSum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps your learning process, but this is what I would do if I needed to do that logic.

Use Range to generate a collection of consecutive integers, up to `n`, then do a *projection* with LINQ of another collection from 1 to each value, then sum and convert to array.

```
int n = 10;
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, n)
 .Select(e => Enumerable.Range(1, e).Sum()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Hey, I prefer staying with for loops